# mPDF error: Unable to create output file: ../../../tmp/

Tags: php, mpdf

I have the issue "Unable to create output file:" when output pdf using mPDF in php,

directory that I want to save the pdf is: /opt/lampp/htdocs/sim/tmp

this is my output pdf:

```
$fileName = "example.pdf"
$mpdf->Output("../../../tmp/". $fileName,'F');
```

I tried to change the directory but not working:

```
$mpdf->Output("/opt/lampp/htdocs/sim/tmp/". $fileName,'F');
$mpdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/sim/tmp/". $fileName,'F');
```

Tell me if you know the answer..

Comment: Does the Apache account (or whatever user account runs the PHP) have write access to the directory?

Comment: the folder 'tmp' set = -rwxr-xr-x, i'm not the owner.. so it can't be save to the 'tmp' folder? thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the directory path does not exist or there are insuffient permissions for the user who is running the php script.

Confirm the directory exists and has the proper permissions:

```
ls -ld /opt/lampp/htdocs/sim/tmp/
```

Be sure rwx is set for the user/group of the user whose running the php script.

If the permissions are incorrect you can run:

```
chown <USER> /opt/lampp/htdocs/sim/tmp/
chmod 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs/sim/tmp/
```

Where `<USER>` is the php user.

If you do not have the permissions to change this, you should create a directory in another location, set the permissions accordingly and use that as your PDF save directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
```

You can check your error and resolve it.